# C# Autofac. Регистрация в контейнере коллекции фабрик IEnumerable<Func<MyClass>>

Tags: c#, autofac

Есть несколько реализаций интерфейса IExchangeDataProvider.

**Сервисы:**

```
public interface IExchangeDataProvider
{
     string ProviderName { get; set; }
}

public class DataProvider_1 : IExchangeDataProvider
{
  public string ProviderName { get; set; } = "DataProvider_1";
}

public class DataProvider_2 : IExchangeDataProvider
{
  public string ProviderName { get; set; } = "DataProvider_2";
}
```

**Регистрация в контейнере Autofac:**

```
 builder.RegisterType<DataProvider_1>().As<IExchangeDataProvider>().InstancePerDependency();
 builder.RegisterType<DataProvider_2>().As<IExchangeDataProvider>().InstancePerDependency();
```

Мне нужна не просто `IEnumerable<IExchangeDataProvider>` инжектированная в конструктор, а `IEnumerable<Func<IExchangeDataProvider>>` 
с возможностью выбора нужной фабрики сервиса.

**Резолв зависимостей**

```
    public class MainService
    {
        IEnumerable<Func<IExchangeDataProvider>> _providerFactories;

        public MainService(IEnumerable<Func<IExchangeDataProvider>> providerFactories)
        {
          _providerFactories= providerFactories;
        }

        public void Foo()
        {
          for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
          {
              var providerName= GetProviderName(i); // providerName= "DataProvider_1"
              var dataProviderFactory= _providerFactories.FirstOrDefault("найти фабрику по имени или еще как то для создания именно DataProvider_1 без создания DataProvider_2");
              var dataProvider= dataProviderFactory();
          }
        }
    }
```

Попытался через рефлексию по имении класса, реально создаваемого фабрикой, но тоже не вышло, не нашел его там.

**Сейчас я делаю не рационально (Приходится каждый раз с помощью фабрики создавать новую коллекцию IExchangeDataProvider и уже в ней искать нужный элемент)**

```
public class MainService
{
    Func<IEnumerable<IExchangeDataProvider>> _providerFactories;

    public MainService(Func<IEnumerable<IExchangeDataProvider>> providerFactories)
    {
      _providerFactories= providerFactories;
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
      for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
      {  
          var providerName= GetProviderName(i); // providerName= "DataProvider_1"
          var dataProvider =_dataProviderCollectionFactory()?.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.ProviderName == dataProvider);
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Несложно догадаться, что простое перечисление `Func<...>` вам не подходит в принципе: до момента создания объекта фабрика не дает никакую информацию о том что это будет за объект.

А значит, надо использовать что-то кроме `Func<>`. Например, можно начать с вот такого общего для любых контейнеров способа:

```
interface IExchangeDataProviderFactory 
{
    string ProviderName { get; }
    IExchangeDataProvider CreateProvider();
}

class DataProvider_1_Factory : IExchangeDataProviderFactory 
{
    private readobly Func<DataProvider_1> creator;
    public DataProvider_1_Factory(Func<DataProvider_1> creator) 
    {
        this.creator = creator;
    }

    public string ProviderName => "DataProvider_1";
    public IExchangeDataProvider CreateProvider() => creator();
}
```

Или же можно воспользоваться механизмом метаданных:

```
builder.RegisterType<DataProvider_1>()
  .As<IExchangeDataProvider>()
  .InstancePerDependency()
  .WithMetadata("ProviderName", "DataProvider_1");

builder.RegisterAdapter<Meta<Func<IExchangeDataProvider>>, IExchangeDataProviderFactory>(
    m => new GenericDataProviderFactory(m.Metadata["ProviderName"], m.Value
);

class GenericDataProviderFactory : IExchangeDataProviderFactory 
{
    private readonly Func<IExchangeDataProvider> creator;
    public GenericDataProviderFactory(string providerName, Func<IExchangeDataProvider> creator) 
    {
        ProviderName = providerName;
        this.creator = creator;
    }

    public string ProviderName { get; }
    public IExchangeDataProvider CreateProvider() => creator();
}
```

*На самом деле, можно внедрять сразу `Meta<Func<IExchangeDataProvider>>` без лишних интерфейсов - но это привяжет ваш код к Autofac, чего обычно хочется избежать.*

При желании, можно воспользоваться атрибутами для задания метаданных:

```
[MetadataAttribute]
public class ProviderNameAttribute : Attribute
{
  public string ProviderName { get; }

  public AgeMetadataAttribute(string providerName)
  {
    ProviderName = providerName;
  }
}

[ProviderName("DataProvider_1")]
public class DataProvider_1 : IExchangeDataProvider
{

}

builder.RegisterModule<AttributedMetadataModule>();
```

Наконец, в Autofac есть механизм именованных сервисов:

```
builder.RegisterType<DataProvider_1>().Named<IExchangeDataProvider>("DataProvider_1").InstancePerDependency();
builder.RegisterType<DataProvider_2>().Named<IExchangeDataProvider>("DataProvider_2").InstancePerDependency();

public MainService(IIndex<string, Func<IExchangeDataProvider>> providerFactories) { ... }
```

Comment: Спасибо!! Именованные сервисы с IIndex отлично подходят, про IIndex я не знал и не мог понять как сервисы передать вместе.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вам подойдёт создание именованных зависимостей:

```
// Регистрируем именованные зависимости для DataProvider_1 и DataProvider_2
builder.RegisterType<DataProvider_1>()
    .As<IExchangeDataProvider>).Keyed<IExchangeDataProvider>("DataProvider_1");
builder.RegisterType<DataProvider_2 >()
    .As<IExchangeDataProvider>).Keyed<IExchangeDataProvider>("DataProvider_2");

builder.Register<Func<string, IExchangeDataProvider>>(c =>
{
   var componentContext = c.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
   return (providerName) =>
   {
       var dataProvider = componentContext.ResolveKeyed<IExchangeDataProvider>(providerName);
       return dataProvider;
   };
})
```

Использование в сервисе:

```
public class MainService
{
    private readonly Func<string, IExchangeDataProvider> _providerFactories;

    public MainService(Func<string, IExchangeDataProvider> providerFactories)
    {
        _providerFactories= providerFactories;
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            var providerName= GetProviderName(i);
            var dataProviderFactory = _providerFactories(providerName);
            var data= dataProviderFactory.GetData();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Тоже спасибо за ответ, это работает. Но использование IIndex для передачи коллекции именованных сервисов кажется проше.